# How do you enable multi-touch in cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cocos2d-x

I am working with the iPhone simulator in XCode 5.0.  Cocos2d-x 2.2.0.

I have single touch working without a problem, but I can't seem to figure out what I am supposed to do in order to get the multi-touch turned on?  Events are coming into the touch dispatcher just fine for one touch...just not the second while the first touch is still in effect.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.  I knew I had done this before.  Must need more coffee.

You have to turn it on in one of the "platform" files...in this case, AppController.mm:

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Right after you create the EAGLView*:

```
   // Enable Multitouch
   [__glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```